# How can I enable http logs when I am using firebase-admin-java?

Tags: firebase-admin

I am facing weird error when I am using `firebase-admin-java`. It would be nice to see low level logs to understand error reason. Is it possible to enable http logs how library communicates with firebase server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable and configure logging with SLF4J. See https://medium.com/@hiranya911/logging-in-java-libraries-for-firebase-and-google-cloud-platform-f8742493b73f for details.